# the same...as / that- What's the difference?

Tags: conjunctions

What's the difference among the following?

1. Isn't it the same radio **that** I lost last year?
2. Isn't it the same radio **as** I lost last year?
3. Isn't it the radio that I lost last year?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: "the difference" is very broad.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the natural way of expressing this does not use "it."  You are talking about a specific radio, so you would say "that," or if you are holding it in your hands, you would say "this."

> Isn't that the same radio I lost last year?
>
> Isn't this the same radio I lost last year?

Even better is a modification of your last option

> Isn't this the radio I lost last year?
>
> Isn't that the radio I lost last year?

You can insert the second "that"

> Isn't this the radio that I lost last year?

To address your original question about "as" and "that," I would not use "as" without any other words in this context.  You could expand it to

> Isn't this the same radio as the one I lost last year?

But it's overly wordy in my opinion.

Comment: Are you a native speaker of English? Also, you haven't explained the difference between "the same...as..." and "the same...that...," even if the former contains the extra words.

Comment: Yes, I'm a native speaker, located in the US.  I'm not sure I can really explain the theoretical differences between the "as" and "that" usages.  Instead I just presented the normal cases you see, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Both **as** and **that**  can be introducers of a relative clause. They serve the same  purpose. However, the word **as** has fallen out of use in this role; it was far more popular [in the 18th and 19th centuries](https://books.google.com/books?id=0uU-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA64&dq=%22those%20as%20have%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD4Ji_tpTaAhVHTt8KHc_6DYUQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22those%20as%20have%22&f=false) than it is in standard English today, though it does survive in regional dialects.  Thus, using **as** today in that role could well have sociolect implications.

Your question is complicated by the fact that **same** is involved, and **same...as** is still current.

> My car's the same color as his.   <sup>standard/idiomatic</sup>
>
> That's the same car as was stolen last year. <sup>non-standard</sup>

Comment: I was told that "the same...as..." (with "as" introducing a relative clause) is about identity of model / make of something, whereas "the same...that..." expresses total identity, .i.e. "same"  can be left out without changing the propositional meaning.

Comment: You were told something far too specific. What if the thing in question is not a manufactured item?  And I don't have a clue what you mean by "total identity".

Comment: Some people say "This is the same book that I lost last week" is equal to "This is the book that I lost last week."

Comment: So your question is about the word **same** and not about the words you bolded in the question?

Comment: My question is about the constructions "the same...that" and "the same...as."

Comment: The difference depends on what fits into the gap you've left here in that last comment with [...], and which follows your **as**, as I show in my answer. Do you see a difference between *as his* and *as was stolen last year*?

Comment: Is " "This is the same book that I lost last week"  equal to "This is the book that I lost last week"? If so, that's what I meant by total identity.

Comment: What do you mean by **equal**?

Comment: Propositionally equal.

Comment: What do you mean by "propositionally"?  Does speaker's state of mind factor into it?

Comment: Presumably, pragmatics does not matter in propositional meaning. But I am not sure how the speaker's state of mind has relevance to the propositional, or truth-conditional, meaning.

Comment: **same** can merely provide emphasis (I've lost that book *twice* now!) or it can denote "identity" (This is indeed the very same book I lost last week -- we have found it.)  In one scenario the book is lost, in the other, found. Opposite meanings, propositionally. P.S. Since **this** is deictic, context is essential to our understanding of the statement.